# Is there a way to remove animated gifs from Google+ videos?

Tags: google-plus

I have disable GIFs from being created through turning off *Auto enhance* but already have a bunch of videos on Google+ which have animated GIFs. This makes the videos preview take forever to load. Not sure If I can remove the GIF preview while keeping the video. I could delete them all and re-upload them but that could take days. I just want to get rid of the GIF preview, nothing more.